# Selecting only the top 10 of a count in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

I need to create a query in which I only select a top ten of a count in oracle and I cannot seem to get it right.  I have read about using rank but so far, I have not figured it out.

```
select col , count(col) from table_name group by col
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap this query with another one, and use the `rownum` pseudocolumn:

```
SELECT col, cnt
FROM   (SELECT   col , COUNT(col) AS cnt
        FROM     table_name 
        WHERE    col IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY col
        ORDER BY 2 DESC)
WHERE  rownum <= 10
```

Comment: That seems to be very close but I am getting a error. "not a single-group group function."  I thought adding another group by at the end of the statement would work but then the col count only comes back as one for each one.

Comment: Scratch that.  It does work. entered in the cnt is the first select statement wrong.  Now I see that my top value returned is for all the null/empty values in the column.  I need to exclude that one which hopefully will be pretty simple.

Comment: @WeVie Added a `where` clause to exclude empty `col`s - should do the trick.